# See mails sent from other application using gmail address

Tags: gmail

I have some self application that sends out automatic mails using my gmail address.
Is there an option for me to see the sent mails in the regular gmail interface (under 'sent' label)? right now I don't see them.
Thanks.
This is the configuration:

```
'mailer' => [
    'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
    'transport' => [
        'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
        'host' => '****************.co.il',
        'username' => '*************',
        'password' => '***********',
        'port' => '587',
        'encryption' => 'tls',
    ],
],
```

This is the actual send:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
        ->setFrom('************@gmail.com')
        ->setTo($candidate->email)
        ->setSubject('Some subject')
        ->setTextBody('Some Body...')
        ->send();
```

Comment: How are you sending them?

Comment: Using mail sender of some php framework, using a hosting server.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you are using to send the email then.  I suspect sent label is something that is added by the Gmail web application.  Your going to have to add this to your code if your using the gmail api to send the mail.   If your going though the SMTP server directly then i would check how that registers sent mails and then update the label though the API